# What does "www" do to my endpoint bindings?

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

So I have been deploying a Silverlight website lately, and I just noticed some pretty horrific bug already.

My Silverlight app has 5 bindings to wcf services hosted on a web app on the same website, just one folder ahead. Let's say my website is **www.test.com**. Here are the bindings from the silverlight app's ServiceReferences.ClientConfig:

```
<client>
    <endpoint address="http://www.test.com/MyWebService/Service1.svc"
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_IService1"
        contract="Service1.IService1" name="CustomBinding_IService1" />
    <endpoint address="http://www.test.com/MyWebService/Service2.svc"
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_IService2"
        contract="Service2.IService2" name="CustomBinding_IService2" />
    <endpoint address="http://www.test.com/MyWebService/Service3.svc"
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_IService3"
        contract="Service3.IService3" name="CustomBinding_IService3" />
    <endpoint address="http://www.test.com/MyWebService/Service4.svc"
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_IService4"
        contract="Service4.IService4" name="CustomBinding_IService4" />
    <endpoint address="http://www.test.com/MyWebService/Service5.svc"
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_IService5"
        contract="Service5.IService5" name="CustomBinding_IService5" />
</client>
```

So my problem is that when I load the Silverlight app, on a default aspx page hosted at the root directory of my IIS website, the connexions only work when I type **test.com** in the URL address, and not when I type **www.test.com**. It doesn't fail, but the data that should be extracted through the services just doesn't show, and I cannot connect with my credentials. (since one of my services is used for authentication)

I tried changing the values i my app's ServiceReferences.ClientConfig by removing the **www**, but the situation does not change one bit. It still connects well without the www in the url, and not when the www is on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, thanks to [this lovely post](http://tonychampion.net/blog/index.php/2011/02/deploying-silverlight-with-wcf-services/), I got to surpass this problem. I will explain what I had to do in here, just in case the link goes dead.

All I had to do was to change each instantiation of each Service Client in my Silverlight code :

```
Service.IService proxy = new Service.ServiceClient();
```

to this :

```
Uri servUri = new Uri("../MyWebService/Service.svc", UriKind.Relative);
EndpointAddress servAddr = new EndpointAddress(servUri);
Service.IService proxy = new Service.ServiceClient("CustomBinding_IService", servAddr);
```

As explained in the blog post, the ".." is necessary since the Silverlight app is (usually) located in the **ClientBin** folder.

And this did the trick for me!